# How to create an error message when user inputs an unidentified answer

Tags: python, controls, user-input

```
def program():

    print ('Start program')

    choice = input("please select either a card or coin?")


    if choice == "COIN":    
        print ("you will now be given heads or tails")
    elif choice == "Coin":
        print ("you will now be given heads or tails")
    elif choice == "coin":
        print ("you will now be given heads or tails")




    import random

    higher_value = 2
    lower_value = 1
    final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

    if final_value == 1:
        print ("Heads")

    else:
        print ("Tails")

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    #CARD

    if choice == "Card":
        print("you will now be given a number for; number,suit")
    elif choice == "card":
        print ("you will now be given a number for; number,suit")
    elif choice == "CARD":
        print ("you will now be given a number for; number,suit")



    import random

    higher_value = 13

    lower_value = 1
    final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)


    if final_value == 1:
               print ("ace")
    if final_value == 2:
               print ("2")
    if final_value == 3:
               print ("3")
    if final_value == 4:
               print ("4")
    if final_value == 5:
               print ("5")
    if final_value == 6:
               print ("6")
    if final_value == 7:
               print ("7")
    if final_value == 8:
               print ("8")
    if final_value == 9:
               print ("9")
    if final_value == 10:
               print ("10")  
    if final_value == 11:
               print ("Jack")
    if final_value == 12:
               print ("Queen")
    if final_value == 13:
               print ("King")


    import random

    higher_value = 4
    lower_value = 1
    final_value = random.randint (lower_value, higher_value)

    if final_value == 1:
               print ("Hearts")
    if final_value == 2:
               print ("Clubs")
    if final_value == 3:
               print ("Spades")
    if final_value == 4:
               print ("Diamonds")

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    #REPEAT LOOP
flag = True
while flag:
    program()
    flag = input('Would you like to run the program again? [y/n]') == 'y'

print ("The program will now terminate.")

print ("Have a good day")
```

I am trying to work out how to make an error when the user inputs the wrong data, for example if he user inputs something instead of the two options of card or coin.

An error message will come up and then ask the user to re-input the data, also when the user was to input card or coin it would produce the results of both card pick and coin toss I would like the program to output either coin or card

Comment: It's better to ask one question per post, so I answered the first one only.

Answer (score 0):

```
choice = choice.lower()
if choice == 'card':
    # do the card thing
elif choice == 'coin':
    # do the coin thing
else:
    # print an error message
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question about displaying an error when the user inputs an incorrect answer, you need to loop each time you ask the user for input:

```
choice = input("Please select either a card or coin: ").lower()
while choice not in ('card', 'coin'):
    choice = input("You did not enter a correct choice, please select either a card or coin: ").lower()
```

Then you need to wrap your logic for doing the work if they suggested card or coin in a large `if` statement:

```
if choice == 'card':
    # card logic goes here
elif choice == 'coin':
    # coin logic goes here
else:
    # Shouldn't reach this (your while loop above should catch it)
    # But error anyway, just in case
```

Comment: don't really understand

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand?

Comment: Great. If this works, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I understand what you have done however I did not work, if I input cooooin instead of coin it will output an error message but continue to run the program, displaying both results for card and coin

Comment: Then you can't have done what I've suggested... we'd have to see your updated code.